# Why is it that drag and dropping frameworks in Xcode 6 leads to problems, am I missing something?

Tags: ios, frameworks, drag-and-drop, xcode6

Pretty much every framework I have ever tried to add to Xcode has recommended drag and dropping it into the project navigator. This has only ever led to problems for me. Initially I would drag the frameworks over from my local `~/Downlaods` folder. This caused issues when I checked in code, someone would pull my changes and  try to run it, but the file could not be found since I was only passing in a reference to the project navigator. As I continued to use Xcode more I could usually get around this by

1) moving the framework in the finder from my `~/Downloads` folder to the folder where I wanted it to go in my Xcode project

2) using `File -> Add files to <app_name>` in Xcode to put the framework into the correct place in the Xcode project

3) Add the framework to the target's build phase as appropriate

Is this what I should be doing? I feel like I am going about this in a very round about and it seems like drag and drop works fine for others on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I think your step 1 is the best thing to do to start because you don't want Xcode to keep looking in your /Downloads folder for the Framework once you add it to the project.  I keep a folder in my Xcode project called "Assets" or something similar.  So if I download a Framework or SDK, I make sure to put it in that folder.  (Though, at this point, even though the Framework is in a folder in my Xcode folder...it is not yet in the project.)

The second step  would then be to simply click your project inside Xcode and scroll down under the "General" tab to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".  Hit the + button, then "Add other" and then find your Framework in the folder you just dragged it to.

You're framework is now ready to go and you don't have to worry about what's going on in your /Downloads folder or any other folders that aren't associated with your project.